# d-flex class in container fluid, making the h1 inside it smaller

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to this field so I hope my question will be written correctly.
im usind a container-fluid, the items in it should be in the vertical center of the page.
the items are an h1 tag (with background color) and a button, I also used a row and columns.
So in the course I'm taking, the teacher use flex-box to align items to the vertical center of the page, but whenever I put the "d-flex" class for the container-fluid, the background of the h1 is getting smaller and not taking the full width of the page like before.

this is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid align-items-center h-100 d-flex">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <header class="text-center">
                <h1><strong>Your Best Working Environment</strong></h1>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <section class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Click Here For More Info</button>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This is the picture was the container-fluid has a "d-flex" class and the h1 background doesn't taking the full width of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSJwQ.jpg)

This is the CSS:

```
body, html{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
background: url(pc.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover
margin:0;} 

h1{
padding: 7px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); }

.container-fluid {
padding-right:0;
padding-left:0;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;}

.flex_centered{
justify-content: center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the `<header>` tag to have a width of 100%. In Bootstrap, this would look like:

```
<div class="container-fluid align-items-center h-100 d-flex">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <header class="text-center w-100">
                <h1><strong>Your Bast Working Environment</strong></h1>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <section class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Click Here For More Info</button>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This also assumes that there is some unseen CSS code that is giving that light black box/padding to the H1

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment! but it's still not working :/ and yeah, ill provide the CSS in the question, maybe it is something there.